# Where to store custom Handlebars helpers in an Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

As part of my learning Node.js, I am doing an app with Express + Handlebars.

I came to the point where I need to register my own helper for Handelbars view engine.

I defined my own helper with registerHelper() method, but I have no idea where I should place this definition within my project structure to make the helper be accessible in my views (preferably globally).

How do you do you go about it?

My project structure is quite basic I think:

```
--bin
--middleware
--models
--node_modules
--public
--views
--routes
app.js
```

In app.js I require handlebars module and setup the layout engine with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question as I found it all described neatly in the Handlebars documentation, of course: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars#helpers

Turns out you can add a property called *helpers* when you define your Handlebars engine in (in my case) app.js. THat property holds an object with methods you define as helpers.